# Mongo sort by string value that is actually number

Tags: mongodb

I have collection that contains objects such as this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f00cf47958af95dca29c0c"), 
    "id" : "...", 
    "threadId" : "...", 
    "ownerEmail" : "...@...", 
    "labelIds" : [
       ...
    ], 
    "snippet" : "...", 
    "historyId" : "35699995", 
    "internalDate" : "1422773000000", 
    "headers" : {
        "from" : "...@...", 
        "subject" : "....", 
        "to" : "...@..."
    }, 
    "contents" : {
        "html" : "...."
    }
}
```

When accessing objects, I want to sort them by iternalDate value, which was supposed to be integer, however it is a string. Is there a way to sort them when fetching even if these are strings? By alphabetic order? Or is there a way to convert them to integer painlessly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to me that the best solution here would be to parse it first as an integer. You could do it using a simple script in javascript like this, using the mongodb client for node:

```
db.collection.find({}, {internalDate: 1}).forEach(function(doc) {
    db.collection.update(
       { _id: doc._id },
       { $set: { internalDate: parseInt(doc.internalDate) } }
    )
})
```

Answer (score 63):

Collation is what you need...

```
db.collection.find()
  .sort({internalDate: 1})
  .collation({locale: "en_US", numericOrdering: true})
```

Comment: This works on the command line but using spring data this does not seem to have any effect

Comment: Yeah, this works, but try it on 1M+ documents.  It will slow your queries to a crawl.  It does not scale well.  More performant converting to int and then back if necessary.

Answer (score 6):

you also can use the aggregate method to sort number which is actually a string.

```
 db.collection.aggregate([{
     $sort : {
          internalDate : 1
     }
 }], {
     collation: {
         locale: "en_US",
         numericOrdering: true
     }
 });
```

if you are using mongoose-paginate package for serverside pagination .. so don't use this package, use only **mongoose-paginate-v2** for serverside pagination. this package for nodejs side

Answer (score 3):

I was having this issue. I use string length to sort first and then apply the sort of my numeric value stored like a string. e.g. "1", "100", "20", "3" that should be sorted like 1, 3, 29, 100.

```
    db.AllTours.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields : {
            "MyStringValueSize" : { $strLenCP: "$MyValue" }
        }
    },
    { 
        $sort : { 
            "MyStringValueSize" : 1,
            "MyValue" : 1
        } 
    }
    ]);
```

There is a new feature in version 4.0 called [$toInt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/) that can be used to parse your string and then sort. In my case I can't upgrade from 3.6.

Comment: Probably not that useful since `$strLenCP` has nothing to do with the question asked. What is asked is sorting something like `"123"` being *greater than* `"4"`, which as a "string" is not actually true, though it would be *numerically*. That's not what `$strLenCP` ( which returns the **string length** ) actually does. The link in the answer is more accurate than the code example.

Comment: Actually, this do the trick. But in very limited case. This query _indeed_ sorts by string length first, then sort by value. On your case it will put "123" below "4" because "123" length is bigger. If there are more than one rows that have 3 digit number, it will use second sort as tie breaker. But this query only solve for natural numbers, eg: this will not work for negative or floating numbers.

Answer (score 1):

With aggregate, this works for me.

```
db.collection.aggregate([<pipeline>]).collation({locale:"en_US", numericOrdering:true})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution and it worked for me

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
{
    $project: {
        newMonth: {
            $cond: { if: {
                $and: [
                    {$ne: ['$month', '10']},
                    {$ne: ['$month', '11']},
                    {$ne: ['$month', '12']},
                ]
            }, then: {$concat: ['0', '$month']}, else: '$month' }
        }
        }
    },

    {
        $sort: {newMonth: -1}
    }
])
```