# How to convert from string to number in nodejs mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

How can I convert publicationDate from string to number/int using mongoose on nodejs? I would like to then sort my data by year.
Thank you.

Here is my code :

```
app.get("/getAlbumData.json",(req,res)=> {
    Wasabi.find( {publicationDate: { $in: ['2009','2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016'] } }, function (err, doc) {
            res.send(doc);
            res.end();

    }).limit(200)
})
```

Comment: try this 
`Wasabi.find( {publicationDate: { $in: ['2009','2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016'] } }, function (err, doc) {
            res.send(doc);
            res.end();

    }).limit(200).sort({publicationDate: -1}).collation({locale: "en_US", numericOrdering: true})`

Comment: Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815265/mongo-sort-by-string-value-that-is-actually-number
MongoDB collations: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.collation/

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it into a Decimal, and then use .toNumber, here is an example if you already have moongose imported:

`import Decimal from "decimal.js";`

`const yourNumber =  new Decimal(yourString).toNumber();`

the const yourNumber is now in type number, not Number.